# Address of array in C not assignable to pointer to pointer

Tags: c, gcc

I expected that using the `&` operator on an array of `int` in C would be assignable to `int**` as it works to assign an array of `int` (without the `&`) to an `int*`.The `int` is arbitrary here.

I saw this other question but it does not mention trying to assign `&` of an array of `int` to `int**` but to `int*`.. [Assign address of address of array to pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77305832/4825512)

For example..

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int** a;
    int b[5];
    b[1] = 123;
    
    //a = &b; //< results in output of warning "assignment to ‘int **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)[5]’"
    int* c = b;
    a = &c; //< this works
    printf("*a is %i\n", (*a)[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

From what I've read elsewhere `&b` above is a pointer to an array of `int` thus `int(*)[]`.

It's not clear to me from the following either, because it would fall under the "Except" part because "it is the operand of [...] the unary & operator".

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression of type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

The above is from ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.3.2.1/4: according to.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504570

EDIT: though people have answered "it isn't possible" I still have not seen an explanation as to why this isn't a feature of C. Is there any case where it would cause a problem to allow the above? I don't see how it would make sense even if considering for example calling `free(*a)` as you could also call `free(c)`. A reminder here that I do not appreciate "you should do it this way" answers. Commandeering really poisons stackoverflow i.m.o.. Let people try to figure out what works for them. If all you have is a "moral reason why you shouldn't" you don't have a reason at all.

Comment: `int** a` is a pointer to a pointer to an int. When you dereference `a` that location does not contain a pointer

Comment: The type of `&b` is `int (*)[5]` which is quite different from `int **`.

Comment: *"I expected that using the `&` operator on an array of `int` in C would be assignable to `int**` as it works to assign an array of `int` (without the `&`) to an `int*`."* By that reasoning, you would need an array of `int *` so that you could assign it (without the `&`) to an `int **` (which indeed you could).

Comment: @Ian Abbott that case is included in my question and is not what my question is about

Comment: Whenever you find some confusing behavior around arrays, pointers, and the `&` operator, say to yourself three times: _"arrays are not pointers."_

Comment: I suggest removing the EDIT because it makes no sense and you are just digging yourself into a deeper hole.

Comment: Re "*I still have not seen an explanation as to why this isn't a feature of C*", That's because you didn't ask about any feature you think is missing. What feature is that? /// Re "*Is there any case where it would cause a problem to allow the above?*", `a = &b;` is allowed. However, it doesn't make sense to do it since it produces garbage. That's what the warning is telling you.  /// Re "*A reminder here that I do not appreciate "you should do it this way" answers.*", Neither of the answers say what you should do. They only explain why you get a warning from `a = &b`, like you asked.

Comment: I think your confusion is that `int []` is converted to `int *` in most expressions (by the "array decay" rule) so that you should be able to assign the address of that `int *` to an `int **`. The problem is that the operand of the unary `&` operator needs to be an *lvalue*, but the pointer value resulting from "array decay" is not an *lvalue*, i.e. it has no address. That is why unary `&` is an exception to the "array decay" rule.

Comment: That's a very dense way of saying that `&` returns the address of something. You can only return the address of something in memory because only things in memory have addresses. We call those things objects, and they include variables. So while using an array (`int []`) can degenerate into a pointer value (`int *`), you can't get the address of that pointer value anymore than you could get the address of `42`.

Comment: Another way to think about it: If unary `&` was not an exception to the "array decay" rule, then `int b[5];` `int **a = &b;` (with `b` decaying to an `int *`) would make as much sense as `int *c = &1;`.

Answer (score 2):

`int **a` means `a` is a pointer to a `int *`.

There are no `int *` objects in `b`, only `int` objects. The only `int *` object in your program is `c`. Thus, the only address that could be stored in `a` is that of `c`.

`&( b[0] )` yields an `int *`, so I believe you are trying for `&( &( b[0] ) )`. This would yield an `int **`, except you can't take the address of a value. You can only take the address of an object (e.g. a variable). So this doesn't work either.

---

The only option that would allow you to remove the `int *c` is to use an anonymous object.

```c
int **a = &( (int*){ b } );   // Same as `int *c = b; int **a = &c;`.
```

The anonymous object has the same lifetime as `c` would have: automatic, i.e. it's "on the stack". So using this in a function and returning the value of `a` would a problem (just as if you had used `c`).

No advantage is gained by using an anonymous object, so this isn't a recommendation.

---

> From what I've read elsewhere `&b` above is a pointer to an array of `int` thus `int(*)[]`.

Close. It's an `int(*)[5]`.

Comment: A cast actually works as well. Thus `int** c = (int**)&a;` works fine. I don't understand why this cast is required as the conversion is valid.

Comment: I think you mean `int** a = (int**)&b;`? It does not work fine. `*a` isn't an `int *`, so trying to use `a` would result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MaartentenVelden C allows you do take a `bananas* b` and do `int** c = (int**)b;` just fine. Problems appear when you start to actually use and de-reference `c`.

Comment: If OP wants to avoid using `&`, they could create an anonymous `int *[1]` object: `int **a = (int *[]){ b };`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah between that version and the one in the answer... I think I prefer `int** a = (int*<::>)<%false[&b]%>;` myself. If you're gonna obfuscate code, better do it in style :)

Comment: @Lundin Actually I was getting confused because OP *does* want to use `&`. :-)

Comment: On a serious note, the `int**` is what should be avoided in the first place. That's where all the problems are coming from.

Comment: Sad that this conversation devolved into "this is how you should do it I know better". Commandeering people really poisons stackoverflow i.m.o.. Let people try for themself what works for them. Seems like you are correct @Lundin. It actually worked once using mingw gcc for me, not sure why. Trying elsewhere it didn't work.

Comment: Re "*not sure why*", Undefined behaviour means anything could happen, including what you might consider "working". But the behaviour is unpredictable. It could even change within the same run!

Comment: @MaartentenVelden What ikegami just said, there is no trying in programming. Either you know what the code you are writing does, or you don't. If you don't, it's still perfectly possible to write code which _seems_ to work fine but will break later, once the code has entered the territory of "undefined behavior". There's no black and white "always works"/"never works". Unless the code is 100% correct, then it always works.

Comment: @Lundin *"C allows you do take a `bananas* b` and do `int** c = (int**)b;` just fine."* Only if the value of `b` is correctly aligned to point to an `int *`, otherwise it is UB without even dereferencing `c`. (I know *you* know that, but OP probably has not considered it.)

Answer (score 2):

As has been said before, **arrays are not pointers**, but they may decay into a pointer to their first element when used in most expressions. `int* c = b;` works because `b` decays into such a pointer.

Then you have found the part of the C standard naming the few exceptions when decay *does not* happen. For example when taking the address-of operator, `&b`. Since `b` does not decay here, we get an array and then we take the address of an array, which would result in the type "pointer to array" (of `int`), type `int(*)[5]` in this case. Nowhere are we dealing with a pointer to `int` here. There is no decay, there is no pointer to the first element.

Consequently, `a = &b` is invalid because they are incompatible and unrelated pointer types. Just forget about `int**` having anything to do with `int` arrays of any dimension - it doesn't - and anyone telling you otherwise is just confused. `int**` can be used to point at the first item in an array of `int*` if you happen to have one of those, but that's the only case when it can be used together with arrays.

`a = &c;` works because `c` is a separate pointer variable and `a` is pointing at that one. It is not pointing directly at the array.